# How do I prevent a div from going off the screen?

Tags: html, css

Right now I have a div that I need to have over 100vw in width in order to get the effect I want. What I don't want is for the div to go off the right side of the screen. I want the view to stay at 100vw, no horizontal scroll bar. I have tried `overflow: hidden;` and `overflow-x:hidden;` and it is not working.

CSS

```
.stripe {
    height: 500px;
    width: 150vw;
    top: 350px;
    margin-left: -30vw;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4775de;
    transform: rotate(6.2deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div styleName='hero'>

   <div>
        <div styleName="stripe"/>    
   </div>
    <div className="container" styleName="divide-container">
       <div styleName="upper-wrapper" >
       </div>
       <div styleName="lower-wrapper" >
            <MainButtonRow/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of ReactJS are you using? - Just because I tried editing your code as a snippet but it wouldn't display anything. `:-(`

Comment: what library are you using that utilises the styleName attribute. I have never seen that before (quick google determines its react-css-modules)

Comment: 1. Sorry for the confusion, the issue does not involve reactjs but I am using it
2. Stylename is an npm package which allows you to seperate css module classes from styles

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `.hero` has no padding or margin, give the parent div of `.stripe` `width:100%` (or `100vw`) and `overflow-x: hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add another div for wrapping the stripe div. and give overflow:hidden. please refer below code.

css

```
.wrap{position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div styleName='hero'>

   <div className="wrap>
        <div styleName="stripe"/>    
   </div>
    <div className="container" styleName="divide-container">
       <div styleName="upper-wrapper" >
       </div>
       <div styleName="lower-wrapper" >
            <MainButtonRow/>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the overflow in the body tag worked for me when I had this issue.

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```